# Add UTC date and time to database in java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I want to add UTC date and time to my mysql database as timestamp. Previously I tried using SimpleDateFormat as:

```
        //UTC based issued date and expiry date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        final String currentUtc= sdf.format(new Date());
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date currentDate = (Date) simpleDateFormat.parse(currentUtc); //java.util.date
```

It worked but I found that use of SimpleDateFormat is not recommendated. So now I am using Instant date time api as:

```
 Instant currentInstant = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS); //gives UTC datetime
```

which is correctly giving me current time in UTC. 
The problem is then when I add this instant to my database it gets converted to local date by adding my UTC time offset to that instant which I don't want.

```
    //adding UTC time to database but not working
    ps.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.from(currentInstant));
```

So how to add UTC date without adding UTC time offset to my database? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What MySQL datatype are you saving to? I don’t have the experience, but I would expect `timestamp` to work better than `datetime` for UTC datetimes.

Comment: i am saving to Timestamp datatype in my mysql database

Answer (score 1):

### JDBC 4.2

```
    ps.setObject(1, currentInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Since JDBC 4.2 we can directly pass java.time objects to and from JDBC objects like `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`. Perhaps surprisingly we should no longer use `setTimestamp` or similar specific methods, but just `setObject` and `getObject`. In this way they have managed to add new functionality without changing the API specification (the methods `setObject` and `getObject` were already there).

Some JDBC drivers accept just `ps.setObject(1, currentInstant);`, which is logical. I don’t remember whether Connector/J for MySQL does. In any case, it is not specified in the JDBC standard, which requires an `OffsetDateTime` rather than an `Instant`. So I’d use the longer form above, which converts to `OffsetDateTime`, if only for portability.

And congrats on leaving `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp` behind. They had their time, but were all always poorly designed, so I agree in not using them.

Comment: i am getting this error: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x0B\x0A\x00\x00\x07\xE3\x05\x15\x05\x01\xF8\x00x' for column

Comment: That’s too bad. I cannot immediately say why. I tried pasting the error message into my search engine, but it seems it’s mostly finding examples of where the message came with the old date-time classes. You may try searching deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correctly. It happened because Mysql Database automatically converts UTC DateTime to system timezone. If you really want UTC DateTime then you can set the timezone of your MySQL database as

```
SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00';
```